# "contribute" or "contributes"?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Which of the following sentences is correct?

> In a nutshell, planting trees **contributes** to air quality, to forest habitats, to family unity and to kids’ happiness.

> In a nutshell, planting trees **contribute** to air quality, to forest habitats, to family unity and to kids’ happiness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Planting trees is a good thing. It is a good thing.
Swimming daily is good exercise. It is good exercise.

These gerunds are third person singular nouns. It takes the singular.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, "planting" is a gerund. Therefore, it should be **contributes**.

Comment: Welcome! Please don't use your answers to advertise other sites!

Comment: Thank you. I'm sincerely sorry for that, I didn't know it was considered advertising.

Comment: Sure! You can certainly use other websites to support your answer but just linking to them isn't very helpful to our users. The preferred method here is to include the link and quote the relevant parts of the page. This has two functions 1. it saves the user having to visit the other site 2. it prevents your answer from becoming less valuable should the site shut down or the link change. The useful information is maintained because it's included directly in the answer :D

Comment: Oh, okay. Thank you so much for taking your time to frame such an elaborate answer to raise my awareness! Much appreciated.